# Wrong value displaying from Database

Tags: php

I am trying to create a simple app to display a managers in/out of office status. I am going to put a screen in our reception area to display the status's when the app is complete but I am stuck. Could someone please point me in the right direction.
Basically, i am using a while loop to display each record from a MySQL database. Each time an image of a manager is clicked, a piece of javascript changes the in/out status and then i have a save button. Everything works except this one thing... When the page loads, some data is displayed incorrectly. I can manipulate each record with javascript and save its updated value to the database. But when i refresh the page, some values are incorrect (although they are correct in the back end). Here is my HTML/PHP -

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
         <ul id="blurContainer">
             <?php while ($record = $stmt->fetch()) { ?>    
                <li id="<?php echo $record['id']; ?>">  
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $record['id']; ?>" name="id[]" id="id">
                     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $record['status']; ?>" name="status[]" id="status<?php echo $record['id']; ?>">
                    <img id="overlay" src="<?php echo $record['image']; ?>" />
                 </li>      
             <?php } ?>
         </ul>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="update">
</form>
```

Here is what i get from the browser on page load -

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
        <ul id="blurContainer">

                <li id="1" style="opacity: 1;"> 
                     <input type="hidden" value="1" name="id[]" id="id">
                    <input type="hidden" value="out" name="status[]" id="status1">
                    <img id="overlay" src="images/jk.jpg">
                </li>       

                <li id="2" style="opacity: 1;"> 
                    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="id[]" id="id">
                    <input type="hidden" value="out" name="status[]" id="status2">
                    <img id="overlay" src="images/km.jpg">
                </li>       

                <li id="3" style="opacity: 1;"> 
                <input type="hidden" value="3" name="id[]" id="id">
                    <input type="hidden" value="out" name="status[]" id="status3">
                    <img id="overlay" src="images/ap.jpg">
                </li>       

                <li id="4" style="opacity: 1;"> 
                     <input type="hidden" value="4" name="id[]" id="id">
                    <input type="hidden" value="out" name="status[]" id="status4">
                    <img id="overlay" src="images/lb.jpg">
                </li>       
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="update">
    </form>
```

All is correct except these lines -

```
<input type="hidden" value="out" name="status[]" id="status1">

<input type="hidden" value="out" name="status[]" id="status3">
```

Where the value should read 'in'.

I am stumped!!

I am sure this is something simple but i have no idea! Any help would be much appreciated!! Thanks in advance.

my update.php and .js-

```
<?php require 'start.php'; ?>
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];

    for ($x = 0; $x < 4; $x++) {
        $query = "UPDATE details SET status = :status WHERE id = :id";
        $update = $db->prepare($query);
        $update->bindValue(':status', $status[$x]);
        $update->bindValue(':id', $id[$x]);
        $update->execute(); 
    } 

} else {
    echo 'not working';
}

header('Location: ' . BASE_URL . '/index.php');

 ?>


$(function() {
    $("#blurContainer li").on('click', inOut).click();
});

function inOut(e) {
var ID = e.currentTarget.id;
  var elem = document.getElementById(ID);

    if (elem.style.opacity == 0) {
    elem.style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById("status" + ID).value = 'out';
    } else {
    elem.style.opacity = 0;
    document.getElementById("status" + ID).value = 'in';
    }
}
```

Comment: Explode the status value and Use a for loop to display the fields as well as values

Comment: please provide JS and update.php code.

Comment: are you sure status in the database is "in" of those records at the moment you refresh your page?

Comment: Hi Poria, thanks for the quick response! I will look into this solution, thanks

Comment: Hi xAqweRx, i have added the .js and update.php scripts. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mario Plantosar, yes the values of these records is definitely 'in'. I have the database open in another window so i can check. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so ive just found that if i change this - <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $record['status']; ?>" name="status[]" id="status<?php echo $record['id']; ?>"> to this <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $record['status']; ?>" name="status[]" id="status">. It displays the correct record but then my js doesnt work (i use the id as a reference in the .js)